# Auto indent text in ace editor

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I send some text to ace editor like this:

```js
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
var text = $('#text').val().trim();
editor.setValue(text);
```

```css
#editor {
    height: 300px;
}
#text{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.1.01/ace.js"></script>
<div id="editor"></div>
<textarea id="text">
        <p>
          Test
          </p>
</textarea>
```

Is it possible to auto indent the text so it looks like?:

```
<p>
    test
</p>
```

Comment: This may be of help to you https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/1753

Comment: you can also use https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify